# Game is not working correctly after build,Game over panel appears in start when i generate apk

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, apk

I am working on unity and i have developed clone of color switch game. The game works correctly on my PC. There is no issue in the game but when generate its apk and install on my mobile and play the game than game over panel appears in game play screen and replay button also does not work.I don't know what is the problem. Because everything works correctly on my PC...Please help me. Thanks in adcance

Comment: Are you using PlayerPrefs to save some data for the next game start?

Comment: Nope brother.No playerPrefs are used